# Mex compiling on 64 bit linux - /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++

Tags: matlab, mex

Okay I am trying to compile a mex file on 64 bit linux, ubuntu to be precise with Matlab 2013a.

First it gave a error that it could not find `GLIBCXX_3.4.15`. Which was not part of the 
`/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6`. I found this thread [/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216399/usr-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found) and succesfully created a symbolic link `ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17 libstdc++.so.6` in `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/sys/os/glnxa64`

Now I tried to compile again and now I get `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

This is the output

```
>> mex -v tload3.c

**************************************************************************
  Warning: Neither -compatibleArrayDims nor -largeArrayDims is selected. 
           Using -compatibleArrayDims. In the future, MATLAB will require
           the use of -largeArrayDims and remove the -compatibleArrayDims
           option. For more information, see:
           http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html
**************************************************************************

-> mexopts.sh sourced from directory (DIR = $PREF_DIR)
   FILE = /home/wouter/.matlab/R2013a/mexopts.sh
----------------------------------------------------------------
->    MATLAB                = /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a
->    CC                    = gcc
->    CC flags:
         CFLAGS             = -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE  -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread
         CDEBUGFLAGS        = -g
         COPTIMFLAGS        = -O -DNDEBUG
         CLIBS              = -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64 -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm -lstdc++
         arguments          =  -DMX_COMPAT_32
->    CXX                   = g++
->    CXX flags:
         CXXFLAGS           = -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread
         CXXDEBUGFLAGS      = -g
         CXXOPTIMFLAGS      = -O -DNDEBUG
         CXXLIBS            = -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64 -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm
         arguments          =  -DMX_COMPAT_32
->    FC                    = gfortran
->    FC flags:
         FFLAGS             = -fexceptions -fbackslash -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer
         FDEBUGFLAGS        = -g
         FOPTIMFLAGS        = -O
         FLIBS              = -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64 -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm
         arguments          =  -DMX_COMPAT_32
->    LD                    = gcc
->    Link flags:
         LDFLAGS            = -pthread -shared -Wl,--version-script,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/extern/lib/glnxa64/mexFunction.map -Wl,--no-undefined
         LDDEBUGFLAGS       = -g
         LDOPTIMFLAGS       = -O
         LDEXTENSION        = .mexa64
         arguments          = 
->    LDCXX                 = 
->    Link flags:
         LDCXXFLAGS         = 
         LDCXXDEBUGFLAGS    = 
         LDCXXOPTIMFLAGS    = 
         LDCXXEXTENSION     = 
         arguments          = 
----------------------------------------------------------------


Warning: You are using gcc version "4.7.3".  The version
         currently supported with MEX is "4.4.x".
         For a list of currently supported compilers see: 
         http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release/

-> gcc -c  -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/extern/include -I/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/simulink/include -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE -ansi -D_GNU_SOURCE  -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pthread  -DMX_COMPAT_32 -O -DNDEBUG  "tload3.c"

-> gcc -O -pthread -shared -Wl,--version-script,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/extern/lib/glnxa64/mexFunction.map -Wl,--no-undefined -o  "tload3.mexa64"  tload3.o  -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64 -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm -lstdc++

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

    mex: link of ' "tload3.mexa64"' failed.

Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully.
```

ps there is a another thread with about the same title, [Error building MEX-files (MATLAB 2012a) on Kubuntu '/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219841/error-building-mex-files-matlab-2012a-on-kubuntu-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-ls), unfortunatly the answer, installing `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6-4.4-dev` did not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and this worked for me

Navigate to the following path `cd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/sys/os/glnxa64/`, (your path might  varies) then remove the libstdc library (or safer rename it)

```
sudo mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.old
```

I have the same configuration, Ubuntu Linux 64 bit with Matlab 2013a

Comment: Thanks I will try that later this day.

Comment: Does not work. It says `Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully.`

Comment: at least the error message changed :) , try on a simple mex file to eliminate any other reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Same problem here on Ubuntu 13.04 using MATLAB 2013a. 
I solved it doing:

```
sudo mv /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6.old
```

To keep a backup just in case.

And then a symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at this line `gcc -O -pthread -shared -Wl,--version-script,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/extern/lib/glnxa64/mexFunction.map -Wl,--no-undefined -o  "tload3.mexa64"  tload3.o  -Wl,-rpath-link,/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64 -L/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lm -lstdc++`.

The options with L are the places where gcc/the linker looks for libraries. Id sugest trying to put the symlink in /usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64 ( libstdc++.so.6 is there in 2012a), and start matlab from a terminal, it spits some errors there. Or add the new folder as a CLIB argument.

And I also would delete the `-ansi` part for c ( replace it with `-std=c99`), so that it won't give you errors on using \ style comments in your c code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just created the `libstdc++.so.6` also in `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64` it however did not help. I still have the same error. Removing the `-ansi-` part did not help either.

Comment: when you start matlab from the console do you get any warnings / errors in the terminal?

Answer (score 2):

You created the link `libstdc++.so.6` in `/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64` to the library in your system, installed by  `apt-get install libstdc++6-4.4-dev` .

Now try creating also a link named `libstdc++.so` to `libstdc++.so.6` in 
`/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a/bin/glnxa64`.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and none of the posted solutions worked for me (i.e. deleting or adding new symlinks), and it turned out that I hadn't installed the appropriate compiler package!

For me, the solution was:

```
sudo yum install gcc-g++
```

I'm running MATLAB 2014b on 64-bit Linux (RHEL 6).