# ld: cannot find -lguide while compiling files using mex with intel c++ compiler

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, compiler-errors, icc

Here is the situation:
Ubuntu 13.04, Matlab 2012a and Intel C++ Composer XE 2013 for Linux.

I downloaded a matlab code archive and followed the instructions in it to compile the .cpp files. Formerly when I finished installing Matlab 2012a and started it, some error messages showed up and I googled out an answer which is:

`sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib64/libc.so.6`

And then there came out another error message which told me 'missing lstdc++' when I started compiling, the idea of re-installing g++ first came into my mind, and the error message disappeared after I did so. However, finally I got an error which I could not find an answer anywhere:

```
>> compilemex
ld: cannot find -lguide
mex: link of ' "max_pool.mexa64"' failed.
Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully.
Error in compilemex (line 20)
eval(exec_string{1});
```

During the the process of searching for a solution, I found [a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000903/mex-compiling-on-64-bit-linux-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lstdc) for my previous 'missing lstdc++' error which differed from what I did to fix it, does this matter or not? And another hint is that I could not find any file named like 'libguide' under the `/opt/intel/` directory, how could I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Googl'ing for libguide, i found this:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/284445

According to this, the build script you're using refers to an old version of the intel compiler. Newer versions seem to have the functions in libguide.so moved to `libiomp5.so`.
So try replacing `-lguide` by `-liomp5`.

Disclaimer: this is pure google knowledge. Personally I have no idea what either library is good for :)