# Matlab 2013 rapid accelerator fails after update (Debian 7 to Debian 8)

Tags: matlab, simulink, mex

I have a simulink model created with Matlab 2013, which was working fine in the rapid accelerator mode on Debian 7 machine.
However, after an update to Debian 8 (and Matlab 2013) the simulation fails with a compilation warning and an error:

Warning:

```
matlab Warning: You are using gcc version 4.9.2  The version currently supported with MEX is 4.4.x.          For a list of currently supported compilers see:...
```

Fatal error:

```
matlab 2013 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit statusmex: link of ' "TestModel_sfun.mexa64"' failed.gmake Error 1
```

A related post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000903/mex-compiling-on-64-bit-linux-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lstdc), which is also a failure at the link step. However the solution, which  for me is to install the package libstdc++-4.8-dev did not help, so something else seems to be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: install the build-essential package.
Turns out a colleague had the same problem earlier.